# Group a list of values using java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a class as following :

```
public class OrganizationRoleDTO {
    private Long organizationId;
    private String organizationTitle;
    private String roleId;
    private String roleTitle;
}
```

In my DAO I have a function that will return a list of `OrganizationRoleDTO`, as following :

```
1, "Organization 1", 1, "Role 1"
1, "Organization 1", 2, "Role 2"
2, "Organization 2", 1, "Role 1"
2, "Organization 2", 3, "Role 3"
3, "Organization 3", 3, "Role 3"
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a new list using the above informations from `OrganizationRoleDTO` list, so the new list will be as following :

```
1, "Organization 1", [{1, "Role 1"}, {2, "Role 2"}]
1, "Organization 2", [{1, "Role 1"}, {3, "Role 3"}]
1, "Organization 3", [{3, "Role 3"}]
```

What I did here is that I grouped the list by the field `organizationTitle`, and the generated list will be of type `OrganizationDTO`, where `OrganizationDTO` is defined as following:

```
public class OrganizationDTO{
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<RoleDTO> rolesList;
}
```

And this is the definition of `RoleDTO` :

```
public class RoleDTO {
    private String title;
    private Long id;
    private List<ProfileDTO> profilesList;
}
```

This is the code I tried:

```
List<OrganizationRoleDTO> organizationRoleList = findOrganizationRoleList();

Map<String, OrganizationDTO> map = organizationRoleList.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, t) -> {
    m.computeIfAbsent(t.getOrganizationTitle(), x -> new OrganizationDTO(t.getOrganizationId(), t.getOrganizationTitle()))
            .getRolesList()
            .add(new RoleDTO(t.getRoleId(), t.getRoleTitle(), profileBP.findProfilsByRoleId(t.getRoleId())));
}, (m1, m2) -> {
    m2.forEach((k, v) -> {
        OrganizationDTO organizationDTO = m1.get(k);
        if (organizationDTO != null) {
            organizationDTO.getRolesList().addAll(v.getRolesList());
        } else {
            m1.put(k, v);
        }
    });
});

List<OrganizationDTO> list = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code is working as expected, the only problem is that it's hard to read and to debug (obvious problem of scalability).

Is there another way to write this ?

Comment: you are missing the definition of `ProfileDTO`

Comment: @Eugene I don't think that `ProfileDTO` definition is needed, but I can provide it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

So, seems like first you might wanna convert it to a "organizationId to OrganizationRoleDTO" map like this:

```
Map<Long, OrganizationRoleDTO> map = organizationRoleList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrganizationRoleDTO::organizationId));
```

Then you just need to convert every map entry to an OrganizationDTO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,  using `CollectingAndThen`

```
List<OrganizationDTO> organizationDTOList = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(OrganizationRoleDTO::getOrganizationTitle),
            stringListMap -> {
              List<OrganizationDTO> organizationDTOS = Lists.newArrayList();
              stringListMap.keySet().forEach(item -> {
                createListOfOrganizationDTO(stringListMap, organizationDTOS, item);
              });
         return  organizationDTOS;
   }));

 private void createListOfOrganizationDTO(Map<String, List<OrganizationRoleDTO>> stringListMap, List<OrganizationDTO> organizationDTOS, String item) {
    List<OrganizationRoleDTO> organizationRoleDTOS = stringListMap.get(item);
    OrganizationDTO organizationDTO = new OrganizationDTO();
    //Set organizationDTO id and title field.
    List<RoleDTO> roleDTOList = organizationRoleDTOS
        .stream()
        .map(this::createRoleDTO)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    organizationDTO.setRolesList(roleDTOList);
    organizationDTOS.add(organizationDTO);
  }

  private RoleDTO createRoleDTO(OrganizationRoleDTO organizationRoleDTO) {
    RoleDTO roleDTO = new RoleDTO();
    roleDTO.setId(organizationRoleDTO.getRoleId());
    roleDTO.setTitle(organizationRoleDTO.getRoleTitle());
    return roleDTO;
  }
```

But this is not great either.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your model. I added some methods in the models and also defined `Function` and `BiFunction` to simplify.

```
BiFunction<OrganizationDTO,OrganizationDTO,OrganizationDTO> function = 
  (o1,o2)-> new OrganizationDTO(o2.getId(),o2.getTitle())
   .setRoleList(Stream.of(o1.getRolesList(),o2.getRolesList())
   .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and `Function`

```
 Function<List<OrganizationDTO>,OrganizationDTO> dtoFunction = 
   l->l.stream()
  .reduce(new OrganizationDTO(),
         (o1,o2)->function.apply(o1,o2));
```

Added these methods into `RoleDTO` class.

```
public OrganizationDTO addRole(Long id, String title){
    this.getRolesList().add(new RoleDTO(title,id));
    return this;
}
public OrganizationDTO setRoleList(List<RoleDTO> roleList ){
    this.getRolesList().addAll(roleList);
    return this;
}
```

**and final solution**

```
List<OrganizationDTO> result = list.stream()
     .map(organizationRoleDTO -> new OrganizationDTO(organizationRoleDTO.getOrganizationId(), organizationRoleDTO.getOrganizationTitle())
       .addRole(Long.parseLong(organizationRoleDTO.getRoleId()),organizationRoleDTO.getRoleTitle())).collect(Collectors.toList())
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrganizationDTO::getTitle))
      .values()
      .stream()
      .map(dtoFunction::apply)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work: (the list of profiles is replaced with an empty arraylist)

```
public Map<String, OrganizationDTO> toOrganizationDTOMap(List<OrganizationRoleDTO> list) {
    Map<String, List<OrganizationRoleDTO>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrganizationRoleDTO::getOrganizationTitle));

    Map<String, List<OrganizationDTO>> map1 = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), toOrganizationDTO(e)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue));

    return map1;
}

private List<OrganizationDTO> toOrganizationDTO(Map.Entry<String, List<OrganizationRoleDTO>> e) {
    return e.getValue().stream().map(o -> new OrganizationDTO(o.getOrganizationId(), o.getOrganizationTitle(),
            e.getValue().stream().map(ob -> new RoleDTO(ob.getRoleTitle(), ob.getRoleId(), new ArrayList<>()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is `reduce` your original list to a compact item.

```
Map<String, OrganizationDTO> map = organizationRoleList.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(OrganizationRoleDTO::getOrganizationTitle,
                            mapping(OrganizationDTO::of,
                                    reducing(new OrganizationDTO(), OrganizationDTO::add))));
```

To support reduce, you should add some method to your `OrganizationDTO` class:

```
@Data
public static class OrganizationDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<RoleDTO> rolesList;

    public OrganizationDTO() {

    }

    public static OrganizationDTO of(OrganizationRoleDTO source) {
        OrganizationDTO newOrganization = new OrganizationDTO();
        newOrganization.setId(source.getOrganizationId());
        newOrganization.setTitle(source.getOrganizationTitle());

        List<RoleDTO> rolesList = new ArrayList<>();
        rolesList.add(new RoleDTO(source.getRoleTitle(), Long.parseLong(source.getRoleId())));
        newOrganization.setRolesList(rolesList);
        return newOrganization;
    }

    public OrganizationDTO add(OrganizationDTO other) {
        if (id.equals(other.getId())) {
            return this;
        }
        rolesList.addAll(other.getRolesList());
        return this;
    }
}
```